# Express does not render static files once 404 page is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to add a 404 page to my express application, however once I add the route to the 404 page, the static files do not render (e.g. cannot get 'stylesheet/main.css').

The advice is always to put any 404 pages as the very last route, which I have done so and yet it still gives a 404 page for any static content (but not for other routes). It all works fine if I remove the function below the `//Add 404 page for unknown routes` comment.

Why is this and what can I do to rectify it?

Code below:

```
//modules
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    errorPages = require('./controllers/errorPages.js');

//start express
var app = express();

// set-up environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret code...'));
app.use(express.session());
//Redirect to login for all requests if user is not logged in at /dash
app.use('/dash', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.session.auth) {
        res.location('/login');
        res.send(307, null);
    }
    next();     
});
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//start routes from routes.js file
require('./routes')(app);

//Add 404 page for unknown routes
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    errorPages.get(req, res, 404);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
//Add 404 page for unknown routes
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
   errorPages.get(req, res, 404);
});
```

Use this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    errorPages.get(req, res, 404);
});
```

and Add this middleware in the last.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But out of interest why does this work?

Comment: Your `app.all(*` will be executed for all routes. It can be used when you wanted to do certain action all routes irrespective of final response. But later is the route for not served path.